Using the python interactive repl in VS Code how can I run code as if from project root?
In VS Code, I am developing within a python submodule and wish to run the code line-by-line in an interactive repl. However if I "right click" > "Run in interactive window"  > "Run selection/line in interactive window" then absolute imports from other modules in my project no longer work e.g. from src.other_module import something no longer finds src, a module in my project root. It seems that the interactive repl runs the code from within the parent directory of my_submodule. The trouble is, generally speaking my code is written in my submodule from the project root e.g. cd project_root > python ./module/my_submodule. I need it to default to the project root. Fixing this issue would speed up my development process as I could test lines of code a lot more flexibly than using the debugger for example. For reference, the below project structure gives an illustration of the imports (although the real project is significantly more complicated).
project_root
|__src
   |__other_module
|__module
   |__my_submodule

More broadly, if people have a suggestion of a better way to develop in vs code than I am attempting I would be grateful for it. I am used to developing in jupyter notebooks and would like to keep the flexibility they offer as I develop in .py files.
Thanks for any help!
